# kubernetes pod reschedule and will run in different node after deployment in different namespace

Tags: kubernetes, horizontal-pod-autoscaling

I have two namespace qa and dev. qa and dev pods can run in same node. When I delete the dev release/pods, k8's just reschedules some of the qa pods in different nodes.
Similar things happen when I enable autoscaling that is when scaling down, k8's will reschedule other services pods in the same/different namespace.
1) How do I prevent k8's rescheduling 
2) How do I handle this in case of autoscaling?

Comment: Just out of interest, why do you want to stop K8s from rescheduling? After all, it just tries to evenly balance pods across nodes.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to schedule your pod on specific node then you can use [node selector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#nodeselector).

```
# To set level on node run
$ kubectl label nodes <node-name> <label-key>=<label-value>

# On pod spec set

  nodeSelector:
    <label-key>=<label-value>
```

If you want to prevent re-schedule then use [Pod disruption budget](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/configure-pdb/) and set `maxUnavailable: 0`, it will never remove your pods

```
apiVersion: policy/v1beta1
kind: PodDisruptionBudget
metadata:
  name: pdb
spec:
  maxUnavailable: 0
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: demoapp
```